# Flutter local notification not working on iOS

Tags: flutter

Notifications are working properly on Android but not working at all on iOS (tried on emulator).
I have the code in the main page and the notification doesn't show.
Please note that I already made changes on AppDelegate.swift file.

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
        .requestPermission();

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('icon');

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
            requestSoundPermission: true,
            requestBadgePermission: true,
            requestAlertPermission: true,
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
            macOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('can1', 'Channel 1',
            channelDescription: "Desc here",
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker');

    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'Notification is working!', 'Hello world', notificationDetails, payload: 'item x');
```

Comment: is there any exception thrown when you call **flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show** method?

Comment: iOS applications do not display notifications while the app is in the foreground unless configured to do so.

Try scheduling the notifications and minimise the app on device or simulator and  it will work

Answer (score 1):

I belive you are missing DarwinNotificationDetails for IOS setting for NotificationDetails

```
const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    AndroidNotificationDetails('can1', 'Channel 1',
        channelDescription: "Desc here",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker');

const DarwinNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = DarwinNotificationDetails();

const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics
);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's happened to me before but different issue (updates problems) on android and finally found that's

1. run command 'flutter upgrade'.
2. run command 'flutter clean'.
3. update to the last package version in pubspec.yaml.
4. delete the IOS folder and then run command 'flutter create .'.
5. now follow the package docs steps.

Comment: Already tried and is not working

Comment: Then you have to read all md file of package might you have version issue which will be considered in readme.md file

Answer (score -1):

Notification doesnt work in ios emulator, you need to use real device